# mysql grouping same value from one column to echo table

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, grouping

I'm struggling to show the outcome I'm looking for. I need to create a table which can group the rack column which will be the name of the table and the content is from the layout column is the data for the table.

```
 $sql = ' SELECT  rack, id, GROUP_CONCAT(layout) as grouped_name FROM sorting_items GROUP BY rack ORDER BY rack ASC';

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {


        echo '<td>'.$row['rack'].' </td>';
        echo '<table style=" border: 1px solid black; width:100%"><tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['grouped_name'].' </td>'; 
        echo '</tr></table>';
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

My table is this

```
╔══════════╦══════╗
║  layout  ║ rack ║
╠══════════╬══════╣
║  cisco1  ║ case1║
║  cisco2  ║ case1║
║  cisco3  ║ case1║
║  juniper ║ case2║
║  cisco4  ║ case2║
╚══════════╩══════╝
```

im currently getting this

```
╔══════════╦══════════════════════╗
║   case1  ║ cisco1,cisco2,cisco2 ║
╚══════════╩══════════════════════╝
╔══════════╦══════════════════════╗
║   case2  ║ juniper,cisco4       ║
╚══════════╩══════════════════════╝
```

looking to achieve this with the above code

```
╔══════════╗     
║  case1   ║ 
╠══════════╣
║  cisco1  ║ 
║  cisco2  ║ 
║  cisco3  ║ 
╚══════════╝

╔══════════╗
║  case2   ║ 
╠══════════╣
║  juniper ║ 
║  cisco4  ║ 
╚══════════╝
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you actually want in your result data loop is something like this, which splits the `grouped_name` field on commas and then outputs each value on a separate table row:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '<table style=" border: 1px solid black; width:100%">';
    echo '<tr><th>'.$row['rack'].' </th></tr>';
    foreach (explode(',', $row['grouped_name']) as $name) {
        echo '<tr><td>'.$name.' </td></tr>'; 
    }
    echo '</table>';
}
```